# How do I use pandas to convert excel hours format to minutes?

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe but I'm having problem to convert it into minutes

```
data = {'Dates':['2020-07-01', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-03', '2020-07-04', '2020-07-05', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08'], 
    'Time':['01:30:00' ,'1900-01-05 01:30:00', '1900-01-10 01:30:00', '1900-01-15 01:30:00', '1900-01-20 01:30:00', '1900-01-25 01:30:00', '1900-01-30 01:30:00', '1900-02-04 01:30:00'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like the output to be in minutes format:

```
90
7290
14490
21690
28890
36090
43290
50490
```

Comment: you need to explain your logic more, minutes since what?

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved the problem by using various of steps